# How to access request in prisma middleware

Tags: graphql, prisma, apollo-server

I am using typegraphql-prisma and all the resolver are autogenerated. I need to
automatically set the createdBy and updatedBy fields in Prisma models based on the authenticated user's ID, which retrieve from a Firebase token in Express middleware.

//auth.middleware.ts

```
import { Response, NextFunction } from "express";
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";
import { AuthRequest, FirebaseAuthError } from "./../interfaces";

export default async (req: AuthRequest, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  const token = req.headers.authorization?.split(" ")[1];

  try {
    if (token) {
      const decodedToken = await admin.auth().verifyIdToken(token);
      req["user"] = decodedToken;
      
      
    } else {
      req["authError"] = "No token provided";
    }
  } catch (error) {
    const firebaseError = error as FirebaseAuthError;
    console.error("Error verifying token:", firebaseError.message);

    if (firebaseError.code && firebaseError.code === "auth/id-token-expired") {
      req["authError"] = "TokenExpired";
    } else {
      req["authError"] = "Unauthorized";
    }
  }

  next();
};
```

//schema.prisma

```
model User {
  id               String           @id @default(cuid())
  displayName      String           @db.VarChar(256)
  email            String           @unique // The user's email address for login
  passwordHash     String? // Hashed password
  salt             String? // Salt for hashing
  user_type        UserType         @default(INSURER_EMPLOYEE)
  metadata         String?          @db.VarChar(2048)
  insurer_employee InsurerEmployee?
  regulatory       Regulatory?
  photoURL         String?          @db.Text
  phoneNumber      String? // The user's primary phone number, if set
  disabled         Boolean          @default(false) // Whether or not the user is disabled
  createdBy        String?          @db.VarChar(256)
  updatedBy        String?          @db.VarChar(256)
  created_at       DateTime         @default(now())
  updated_at       DateTime?        @updatedAt

  @@map("users")
}
```

I have created prisma middleware but I can't get the user in prisma middlw.

// prismaClient.ts

```
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";

const prisma = new PrismaClient();

prisma.$use(async (params, next) => {
  if (params.action === "create" && params.args.data) {
    console.log("Prisma Data", params.args.data);
    params.args.data.createdBy =
      params.args.data.createdBy || params.args.context.userId;
    params.args.data.updatedBy =
      params.args.data.updatedBy || params.args.context.userId;
  } else if (params.action === "update" && params.args.data) {
    console.log("Prisma Data", params.args.data);
    params.args.data.updatedBy =
      params.args.data.updatedBy || params.args.context.userId;
  }

  return next(params);
});

export default prisma;
```

//server.ts

```
async function main() {
    const app = express();
  
    const allowedOrigins = [
      "https://agentdb-staging.web.app",
      "http://localhost:3000",
      "http://localhost:4000",
      // ... other domains
    ];
  
    app.use(
      cors({
        origin: function (origin, callback) {
          // Allow requests with no origin (like mobile apps or curl requests)
          if (!origin) return callback(null, true);
  
          if (allowedOrigins.indexOf(origin) === -1) {
            const errMsg = "The CORS policy for this site does not allow access from the specified origin.";
            return callback(new Error(errMsg), false);
          }
          return callback(null, true);
        },
      })
    );
  
    app.use(json());
    app.use(cookieParser());
    app.use(authenticate); // Apply the authentication middleware to all routes
  
    const httpServer = http.createServer(app);
  
    const schema = await buildSchema({
      resolvers: [...resolvers, ...customResolvers],
      validate: false,
      authChecker: customAuthChecker, // register the auth checking function
    });
  
    //const prisma = new PrismaClient();
  
    const server = new ApolloServer<Context>({
      schema,
      plugins: [ApolloServerPluginDrainHttpServer({ httpServer })],
      introspection: true,
    });
  
    await server.start();
  
    app.use(
      "/api",
      expressMiddleware(server, {
        context: async ({ req, res }) => ({
          req,
          res,
          prisma,
          user: (req as any).user, // Include user in the context
          authError: (req as any).authError, // Include authError in the context
        }),
      })
    );
  
    await new Promise<void>((resolve) => httpServer.listen({ port: server_port }, resolve));
    console.log(` Server ready at http://localhost:${server_port}/api`);
  }
```